# find ones position in 64 bit number

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the position of two 1's in a 64 bit number. In this case the ones are at the 0th and 63rd position. The code here returns 0 and 32, which is only half right. Why does this not work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
unsigned long long number=576460752303423489;
int i;
for (i=0; i<64; i++)
    {
    if ((number & (1 << i))==1)
        {
        printf("%d  ",i);

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 just for having an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: This type of operation is heavily used in Huffman decoding of bit-streams in codecs- you might find it's hardware accelerated by your CPU and that there's an intrinsic for it.  There is also a technique involve a LUT and a few logic operations that can massively optimise the 32-bit case that you could leverage if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two bugs on the line

```
if ((number & (1 << i))==1)
```

which should read

```
if (number & (1ull << i))
```

Changing `1` to `1ull` means that the left shift is done on a value of type `unsigned long long` rather than `int`, and therefore the bitmask can actually reach positions 32 through 63.  Removing the comparison to 1 is because the result of `number & mask` (where `mask` has only one bit set) is either `mask` or `0`, and `mask` is only equal to 1 when i is 0.

However, when I make that change, the output for me is `0 59`, which still isn't what you expected.  The remaining problem is that 576460752303423489 (decimal) = `0800 0000 0000 0001` (hexadecimal).  `0 59` is the correct output for that number.  The number you *wanted* is 9223372036854775809 (decimal) = `8000 0000 0000 0001` (hex).

Incidentally, `main` is required to return `int`, not `void`, and needs an explicit `return 0;` as its last action (unless you are doing something more sophisticated with the return code).  Yes, C99 lets you omit that.  Do it anyway.

Comment: I just plugged the number into Wolfram Alpha as a sanity check; `0 59` *is* the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Because `(1 << i)` is a 32-bit `int` value on the platform you are compiling and running on. This then gets sign-extended to 64 bits for the `&` operation with the `number` value, resulting in bit 31 being duplicated into bits 32 through 63.

Also, you are comparing the result of the `&` to 1, which isn't correct. It will not be 0 if the bit is set, but it won't be 1.

Shifting a 32-bit int by 32 is undefined.

Also, your input number is incorrect. The bits set are at positions 0 and 59 (or 1 and 60 if you prefer to count starting at 1).

The fix is to use (1ull << i), or otherwise to right-shift the original value and `&` it with 1 (instead of left-shifting 1). And of course if you do left-shift 1 and `&` it with the original value, the result won't be 1 (except for bit 0), so you need to compare `!= 0` rather than `== 1`.

Comment: So, the fix is?  (1ULL?)

Comment: Is there any way I can fix it so that it prints the correct numbers?

Comment: yes (1ULL), and don't compare the result to 1 - instead check that it's not 0. And correct your input.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long number = 576460752303423489;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<64; i++)
    {
        if ((number & (1ULL << i)))   //here
        {
            printf("%d  ",i);    
        }   
    }
}
```

First is to use `1ULL` to represent `unsigned long long` constant. Second is in the `if` statement, what you mean is not to compare with `1`, that will only be true for the rightmost bit.

Output: `0 59`

It's correct because `576460752303423489` is equal to `0x800000000000001`

Comment: Suggest you change 0x800000000000001 to 0x0800000000000001 to make the problem more obvious.  I wish C let you write 0x800_0000_0000_0001.

Comment: @Zack True. I meant to use binary form in the first place (calculated using Windows calculator), but that's even less readable than the hex format.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could have been avoided in the first place by adopting the methodology of applying the `>>` operator to a variable, instead of a literal:

```
if ((variable >> other_variable) & 1)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has some time and multiple correct answers while my should be a comment, but is a bit too long for it. I advice you to encapsulate bit checking logic in a macro and don't use 64 number directly, but rather calculate it. Take a look [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for quite comprehensive source of bit manipulation hacks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) ((var) & (1ULL<<(pos)))

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long number=576460752303423489;
    int pos=sizeof(unsigned long long)*CHAR_BIT-1;    
    while((pos--)>=0) {
        if(CHECK_BIT(number,pos))
            printf("%d ",pos);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Where does CHAR_BIT defined ?

Comment: @M Sharath Hegde: `grep CHAR_BIT /usr/include/*.h` gives `/usr/include/limits.h:#  define CHAR_BIT        8` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h#limits.h)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than resorting to bit manipulation, one can use compiler facilities to perform bit analysis tasks in the most efficient manner (using only a single CPU instruction in many cases).

For example, gcc and clang provide those handy routines:

```
__builtin_popcountll() - number of bits set in the 64b value
__builtin_clzll() - number of leading zeroes in the 64b value
__builtin_ctzll() - number of trailing zeroes in the 64b value
__builtin_ffsll() - bit index of least significant set bit in the 64b value
```

Other compilers have similar mechanisms.

Comment: Which of those gives the answer to the problem in the question?  The `clzll` and `ctzll` more or less work for the specific value under test because there are just two bits set, but for the general case (a value with multiple bits set, such as 0x80F92AD3)...you're going to end up doing bit manipulation, even with those built-ins, aren't you?

Comment: OQ states that there are only 2 bits set. clzll and ctzll will get you both of them.

Comment: And, of course, even in general case using this sort of intrinsics result in fewer iterations of bit counting loop and lead to other nice optimizations (with popcount() being handy in switching between approaches).